# JQuery UI Tabs with AJAX content VERY slow using IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using [JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) with AJAX content.

The loaded data are a [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) element with ~100 rows and 10 columns.

Everything is fine with FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera, **but with IE9 the loaded table is very slow.**

I tried to load the DataTable usin .load() method in IE9 and it is fine, but using JQueryUI tabs it is really not. I tried JQueryUI 1.8.22 and 1.9.1 but the behaviour is the same.

Is someone already dealt with this such of problem?

**EDIT**

In fact the problem is not bound with DataTables but due to "large" content loaded through AJAX into the tab. Futhermore, the loaded JS code, scroll and even CSS :hover are really not reactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a fix tab content height. I don't understand why, by this slows down a lot the browser rendering in IE (8 and 9).

To fix this problem, I replaced the fix tab content height by CSS property `height:90%` and add a fix table height to the `datatable` `sScrollY": "1000px // 90% of the tab content height`. I set up a window event on `resize` to redraw the `datatable` with the right value to fit the window size.

I hope to help all people facing the same IE issue.

Answer (score 1):

IE renders tables particularly slowly when they are hidden/not visible. This is a documented issue. Best thing to do would be:

```
$('#yourTabs').tabs({
    "select": function(ev, ui){
        if(ui.index == whateverIndexYourTableIsIn) {
            dtYourTable.fnAddData(yourData);
        }
    }
});
```

This will only render the table (data) when the table becomes visible, thus not slowing down in IE nearly as much... though IE is still just overall slower than the other new browsers in this regard.

Discussion on IE "hidden innerHTML slowness"

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1389/x#Item_8

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11701/why-does-datatable-run-so-slow-in-ie89-etc../p1

Comment: I guess that "dtYourTabl"e is the DataTables object and "yourData" the table content. Right? The problem is that the page is loaded through AJAX using tab href="myPage.php". Therefore, DataTable object and the data are not available in the main page. Am I miss something? Do you have web documentation to share with me?

Comment: Then put the `DataTable` init code in `myPage.php`. If you need access to the table in your "main page", write your "child page" as a module. This is beyond the scope of "DataTables issues" though...more a structuring thing. I'll edit my answer with a link to the IE issues

Comment: +1 for the links. In fact the problem is not bound with DataTables but due to large content to load into the tab. Futhermore, the loaded JS code, scrolling and even CSS :hover are really not reactive

Comment: @Bouillou: IE9 is definitely slowish, but it should handle 100 rows/10 col OK. Maybe something else is at fault? Do you have lots of JS running on window-level events? `scroll, resize, etc`? Still slow if you skip your DataTables call? Is the table data/html created server-side or are you doing it with DT (`bServerProcessing, aaData, fnAddData, etc`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem was silly : DataTables have `sScrollY` option to use a scrollbar and the tab have `overflow` CSS property. I don't know why, but IE9 spent plenty of time to resolve the visual render. I just remove the `overflow` CSS property and everything is fine.

Comment: I will insert my answer when I find time. Thanks for your time